# kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, bitnami

I'm getting an error when deploying a simple kafka using kafka 3.3

```
kafka 12:58:07.67 WARN ==> KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID not set - If using multiple nodes then you must use the same Cluster ID for each one
kafka 12:58:13.51 INFO ==> Generated Kafka cluster ID 'xxxx'
kafka 12:58:13.51 INFO ==> Formatting storage directories to add metadata...
The kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster. Formatting is only supported for clusters in KRaft mode.
```

This is the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: kafka-deployment
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
              value: "yes"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
              value: "true"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
              value: xxx
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: xxx
          image: bitnami/kafka:3.3
```

I see that the image in bitnami/kafka for kafka:3.3 changed few daysa go but I'm not sure if the issue is related or if missing any requiered env var. It was working fine few days ago.

I was getting similar warnings but kafka always started successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `bitnami/kafka:3.3` which it might point to a different minor relase in bitnami.

What if you depend on a specific revision of an image? For these scenarios, Bitnami also attaches a static (immutable) tag to each revision. In this example, the 3.4.6-r24 tag refers to Redmine 3.4.6 revision 24 and using this tag ensures that users always get exactly the same image every time.

In your case `bitnami/kafka:3.3` image changed few hours ago and points to the commit `6fa209c22f77` which is the same as `bitnami/kafka:3.3.2`.

- https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/tags?page=1&name=3.3

If you want to make sure that you are always going to use the same kafka version from bitnami, just use immutable tags.

In your specific case you can try using `bitnami/kafka:3.3.1-debian-11-r38` as immutable tag.